# what is the difference between a function that returns an object with methods and a variable that is an object with methods

Tags: javascript, function, variables, methods, javascript-objects

So I don't know a lot about best coding practices in JavaScript, but I'm hoping to better understand how functions should be designed to allow them to be called from outside the JavaScript file.

Take the following example. They both essentially do the same thing but one is stored in a variable and the other is a function.

```js
var myVariable1 = {
 add1: function( that ){
  var number = parseInt( that.innerHTML, 10 );
  if( !isNaN( number )){
   document.getElementById( "variableResult" ).innerHTML = number + 1;
  }
 }
};
function myFunction(){
 var object = new Object();
 object.add1 = function( that ){
  var number = parseInt( that.innerHTML, 10 );
  if( !isNaN( number )){
   document.getElementById( "functionResult" ).innerHTML = number + 1;
  }
 }
 return object;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Function or Variable</title>
 <script src="functionorvariable.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <a onclick="myVariable1.add1( this )">4</a>
  <p id="variableResult"></p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a onclick="window.myFunction().add1( this )">7</a>
  <p id="functionResult"></p>
 </main>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is what is the real difference here?
Is it that they are the same just one may perform a little better than the other?
Is one of them "better" than the other?

I'm just beginning to understand ways to accomplish modular design in JavaScript, so my apologies if both of these are bad practice.

Comment: Well, in your case there is little difference but the most significant one is that you can keep calling the function and getting new objects, so if you want to mutate them or something that wouldn't affect anything else that uses the object. Which might also be a disadvantage - you might actually want a shared instance where which you modify from multiple places. Which one to use depends on specific purpose and somewhat on opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFunction` *creates an object and returns that* everytime called. That makes little sense, as the object does not contain any properties, just a function that could just be a regular function.

`myVariable1` is just an object with a function property. It makes sense to group similar functions in one object to not pollute the global scope (and to keep things structured).

Comment: Thanks. I had started down the road of using the "myVariable1" approach when I came across some of my older code using the "myFunction" approach.

I agree it makes little sense to return an object every time, and I imagine in most cases the "myVariable1" approach is more preferred and better performing.

Comment: @JoshBalsillie For your current example it does make more sense to just use `myVariable1` but then again your example is very trivial. Here is a slightly different one `myCounter = { current: 0, increment: function() { return this.current++; } }` in this case you have a counter with a state. Sharing the instance between two things is usually incorrect - you want a separate counter per thing you are counting. So, it depends on circumstances.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks, I agree with your point that objects that hold variables should often be independent objects. In my case I'm using objects that have and will only ever have functions/methods so I don't need the objects to be independent. I'll remember this for the future, as I anticipate I will need to use it when I start making more abstract code.